# John 3:36 & Continual Wrath

Tags: greek, john, historical-interpretation, judgement, grammatical-historical

**Q:** What does the analysis of the **Greek** text indicate for “continuous wrath” against the “object”(person who disbelieves) in Christ?

Put it another way: Does the **Greek** text show from John 3:36 that the rejector of Christ has abiding wrath on him in such a way to prove against annihilation?   Or does such evidence for an anti-annihilation doctrine via John 3:36 find to be insufficient via the **Greek**?

Some might say: “the wrath of God certainly abides on him who rejects Christ, but the wrath burns him out of existence!”  Hence the question I asked!

The wrath of God “**remaining**” on someone sounds to me even in the English to show that eternal conscious punishment is a exegetical & experiential reality.

> “The one who believes in the Son has eternal life. The one who rejects
> the Son will not see life, **but God’s wrath remains on him**.”
> ‭‭John‬ ‭3:36‬ ‭NET‬‬
>
> “He who believes in the Son has everlasting life; and he who does not
> believe the Son shall not see life, **but the wrath of God abides on
> him**.”” ‭‭John‬ ‭3:36‬ ‭NKJV‬‬
>
> “The one who believes in the Son has eternal life, but the one who
> disobeys the Son will not see life—**but the wrath of God remains on
> him**.” ‭‭John‬ ‭3:36‬ ‭LEB

> “Whoever believes in the Son has eternal life; whoever disobeys the
> Son will not see life, **but must endure God's wrath.**” ‭‭John‬
> ‭3:36‬ ‭NRSV‬‬

Comment: Are you not "scraping the bottom of the barrel" to find support for your contention?  God's wrath remains on the person just as Sodom and Gomorrah suffered eternal fire - fire that did not go out until all was consumed. Jude 7.

Comment: @Dottard I never said you had to answer it Dottard.  ;p. Yet, even some would say Jude 7 means that the fire merely burned them away eternally, rather than reach the truth about the eternal punishment of the wicked.

Comment: ... and I never said you did.

Comment: @Dottard True, but I would argue that the Greek could be more expressive/clear than the English despite the English being very clear.  I have a book on Hell that I will read at some point, I am currently reading another book atm, so maybe that book on Hell will give better insight.  I already read a separate book on Hell, then another one I’m halfway through about Heaven & Hell, so there is always more to learn!

Comment: Where do we learn about the eternal punishing of the wicked?

Comment: @Dottard Primarily from Matthew 25:46, Romans 2:5,8,9 also mention “wrath” which when combined with the eternal nature of the texts within the whole of scripture, it is firmly taught that the wicked will suffer eternal punishment: κόλασιν (kolasin) {chastisement, punishment} - Matt 25:46, & eternal destruction of those who don’t know God: 2 Thess 1:9 - ὄλεθρον (olethron) {destruction, ruin}. I assumed obviously that John 3:36 is directly related, and it is.

Comment: That is the point - eternal destruction means just that destroyed eternally.  However, if something take forever to be destroyed, then it is not destroyed at all!!!  Further, we have eternal punishment not eternal punishing.

Comment: @Dottard You are mincing Scripture there! In 2 Thess 1:9, namely: "olethron" the fact that it means destruction or ruin doesn't mean annihilated.  Rather, the destruction is eternal in 2 Thess 1:9 on the wicked, this means that the objects-(people who don't know God) undergo everlasting ruin/destruction. Greek word for Annihilation is: Aphanizo – ἀφανίζω, which means: to remove out of sight, disappear, vanish away.  So you are incorrect on that matter of being destroyed eternally.  Sinners will remain in everlasting ruin.

Comment: I am mincing scripture??  As I sated before, destruction that takes an eternity is no destruction at all.  How can you take a word than means to destroy and make it mean to preserve in the face of destroying fire.  That is twisting Scripture if ever I heard it.  But you believe what you want - I will believe Scripture.

Comment: @Dottard I've been saved for about 10 years now, I believe scripture too.  Believers can err with respect to Scripture interpretation.  It's obvious that eternal destruction is 1 angle of Hell, another Angle is the furnace of fire(Matt 13) where there is weeping and gnashing of teeth.  You also haven't addressed the obvious as I said before: Annihilation is: Aphanizo – ἀφανίζω, which means: to remove out of sight, disappear, vanish away.  2 Thess 1:9 Does NOT use "Aphanizo" so those who are punished with everlasting destruction are in a continual state of ruin.  It appears you are incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

> **JOHN 3:36** *He who believes in the Son has everlasting life; and he who does not believe the Son shall not see life, but the wrath of God abides on him.”*

For the most part, the ‘Greek’ is accurately translated, it is pretty straightforward. BUT - The only *real* part of the Greek that could be ‘argued’ is the translation of ‘on’ - [Greek] ‘*epi*’ - “the wrath of God abides **on** him.”

Arguably that should possibly be translated as ‘in’, that is, “the wrath of God abides **in** him.” But then it would ‘comfortably’ traditional doctrine - but it *would* better fit Biblical doctrine, namely that of the apostle Paul.

> **ROMANS 1:18** *For the wrath of God is revealed from heaven against all ungodliness and unrighteousness of men, who suppress the truth in unrighteousness,* **19** *because what may be known of God is manifest in them, for God has shown it to them.*

Paul explains that [the sense of , or feeling’ of] Gods wrath is an *inward* intuition. Something that ‘man’ [intuitively] ‘perceives’.

So that one Greek word which can legitimately be translated as *either* ‘in’, *or* ‘on’, makes a significant difference. One had God as the originator of that wrath, the other has ‘man’s’ own separated spirit as the originator of that wrath. Huge difference!

Man’s ‘separated’ therefore/thereby ‘unrighteous’ spirit ‘senses’ that unrighteousness, therefore will know it is deserving of Gods wrath - whereas God only has Love for man.

Comment: Some things you said I find confusing, other things you said make sense.  Would you say that such a verse does indeed prove against annihilation?  Could you clarify since it was part of my question?  ;)

Comment: @Cork88 Man (man’s ‘spirit’) is eternal. The difference for believers is that they have eternal ***life***.

Comment: ἐπί with the dative can mean "in", but not with the accusative. So it cannot legitimately be translated as "in" or "on" arbitrarily.

Comment: @DanielRidings That’s interesting - so what is your understanding that it (*epi*) should or could be in this verse? (John 3:36)

Comment: @Dave My understanding? Pretty much the way you introduced your answer, that the translations in general are accurate. I haven't given it a lot of thought, but if we picture wrath as being something other than anthropomorphic, then there are a myriad of ways wrath could be materialized on someone.

Comment: @Dave would it be wrong to place the focus on the verb "remain", such that the wrath of God is hanging over everyone, and the one who does not believe, does not escape it, as the one who trusts the son? The wrath is present over everyone, but some can escape. I don't have any decent commentaries at hand and there are many better than I when it comes to interpretation.

Comment: The "because" in Ro 1:19 I interpret differently, not referring to "wrath". I understand verse 19 as referring to the knowledge of God that all have since it is manifest in creation, but they have suppressed. They should have known, God was revealed to them innately, but they suppressed the truth. Doesn't change a lot though.

Comment: @DanielRidings Appreciate your ‘snippets’ - they provide some good ‘food’ for thought! Thanks.